# How do I scale and set the origin of a draw picturebox with xy coordinates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a series of X,Y coordinates generated from a triangulated method of measurements. I would like to draw lines to the X,Y coordinates on a picture box so the data entry can be validated. My code generates these x,y values to dynamically created textboxes and then draws them on the picture box. Currently it is working but the resulting lines are very small and they are not centered. How can I fix this? The picturebox1 is 500x500. Here is the code

```
 Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    If Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim g As Graphics
        g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics

        Dim x, y, x1, y1 As String
        x = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxX1").Text
        y = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxY1").Text
        x1 = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxX2").Text
        y1 = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxY2").Text

        Dim xi, yi, x1i, y1i As Integer

        xi = Convert.ToDecimal(x)
        yi = Convert.ToDecimal(y)
        x1i = Convert.ToDecimal(x1)
        y1i = Convert.ToDecimal(y1)

        g.DrawLine(New Pen(ForeColor), xi, yi, x1i, y1i)
        Dim x1a, y1a, x2a, y2a As String
        Dim x1ai, y1ai, x2ai, y2ai As Integer
        For n = 3 To Me.TextBoxABPts.Text
            x1a = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxX" & n - 1).Text
            y1a = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxY" & n - 1).Text
            x2a = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxX" & n).Text
            y2a = Me.Controls.Item("myTextBoxY" & n).Text



            x1ai = Convert.ToDecimal(x1a)
            y1ai = Convert.ToDecimal(y1a)
            x2ai = Convert.ToDecimal(x2a)
            y2ai = Convert.ToDecimal(y2a)

            g.DrawLine(New Pen(ForeColor), x1ai, y1ai, x2ai, y2ai)
        Next n

        g.DrawLine(New Pen(ForeColor), x2ai, y2ai, xi, yi)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is almost never the right thing to use. If something causes your PB to be invalidated (minimize-restore form; some other window floats across it), your drawing will be lost.  Do painting in the Paint event if you want it to persist

Comment: Use the Paint() event of the PictureBox and [Graphics.TranslateTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform(v=vs.80).aspx) and [Graphics.ScaleTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I would like to explore this option with the paint event of the picture box, but I wasn't sure how to call that with a button click. The values will be nothing until all the data is entered and button1 clicked. This appears to be the most solid option if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be easier to use .Net Point for working with coordinates. They consist of X and Y integer values. PointF is another structure that is based on singles. Either will work for you. Create a function that can transpose as scale coordinates.

```
Private Function ScaledPoint(Point As Point, Origin As Point, Optional Scale As Double = 1.0) As Point
    Return New Point(CInt(Origin.X + Point.X * Scale), CInt(Origin.Y + Point.Y * Scale))
End Function
```

In you application, define an origin and scale factor. For example:

```
Dim origin As New Point(200, 100) 'Moves all points 200 right, 100 down.
Dim scaleFactor As Double = 5 'Makes drawing 5 times larger.
```

Now where you call g.DrawLine, change it to something like:

```
Dim Point1 As New Point(x1ai, y1ai) 'There are lots of ways to do this.
Dim Point2 As New Point(x2ai, y2ai) 'This is only an example.
g.DrawLine(New Pen(ForeColor), ScaledPoint(Point1, origin), ScaledPoint(Point2, origin))
```

There are lots of ways to define Point1 and Point2.

Comment: I will explore with this and get back to you with my findings. without rewriting a lot, this seems to be a straight forward method

Comment: So with the way Microsoft interprets the X,Y axes, it is mirroring my drawing. Is there a way to invert the axes?

Comment: Yes. Set the Scale factor to a negative value. You will almost certainly want to place the origin lower on the screen, for example Point(0, 800).

Comment: Scaling by a negative number still produces a mirror image but instead is now rotated 180°. I need to mirror what is currently being produced, whether it is scaled a (-) or not. I wonder if i just divide each x and y coordinate by -1 if that will work

Comment: Just use the negative scale factor on the Y coordinates. Use a positive scale factor on the X coordinates.

Comment: Gotcha, why it was ever designed that way I will never know

Comment: My guess is that monitor used to only do text. And it was intuitive to think in terms of line number and column positions. Line number 1 (or zero) was at the top of screen. Later when graphics were added, they didn't want to change their way of think.

Comment: You may want to read this article too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576110/how-do-i-scale-and-set-the-origin-of-a-draw-picturebox-with-xy-coordinates it explains how to change the scale and origin of drawing in dot net. Pay attention to the comments in the answer, that fixes the inverse Y issue.